# setTimeout pass itself as an argument

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to pass the ID of the current timeout to the function it is executing.

```
function test(timeout){       
  console.log(timeout)
}

setTimeout(test,1000,"timeout object") //how to pass a refrence to the current timeout object or id
```

**edit:**

- timeout may be an object (ES6) or a number, anyway I want a reference to it
- I don't want to declare timeout as a global variable, I just want to **pass it as an argument**

Comment: by timeout object you mean any kind of object, or the return of the setTimeout function ?

Comment: `timeouts` are not an object, they are an integer ID

Comment: What exactly do you want? A reference of the `setTimeout` function?

Comment: the return of setTimeout @GrégoryNEUT

Comment: in modern browsers & nodeJs they are objects, any way I want to pass it even if it is a number @mhodges

Comment: yes @NelsonOwalo

Comment: What are you trying to do with the ID inside the function? The only use for the ID returned from `setTimeout` would be if you wanted to call `clearTimeout` to stop the timeout from running, but once you're in the function that means the timeout has already happened so it can't be canceled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the timeout reference in a variable which will be available inside of the passed function.

```js
var timeoutReference = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('do something with the timeout reference');
    console.log('timeoutReference = ',timeoutReference);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @xxyy Just FYI, this creates a "global" variable just like the other solutions.

Comment: @xxyy This does not work for the example you posted in a comment above. And it creates a global variable, which you explicitly said you didn't want..

Answer (score 3):

I would create an utility function and then use it any time I need it.

Also @Velimir Tchatchevsky answer is the best to use. The wrapper soluce must be way overkill.

```js
function setTimeoutWrapper(func, time) {
  const ref = setTimeout(() => {
    func(ref);
  }, time);
}

setTimeoutWrapper((timeoutReference) => {
    console.log('timeoutReference = ', timeoutReference);
}, 1000);
```

---

Also I don't see the point of passing the reference to the function, because if you are into the function, it means it get called. So there is no need for `clearTimeout` there.

---

---

*Because overkill is fun :*

```js
function setTimeoutWrapper(func, time, ...args) {
  const ref = setTimeout(() => {
    func(ref, ...args);
  }, time);
}

setTimeoutWrapper((timeoutReference, p1, p2) => {
  console.log('timeoutReference = ', timeoutReference);
  console.log('p1 = ', p1);
  console.log('p2 = ', p2);
}, 1000, 'I am a parameter', 'second param');
```

---

What about some IIFE and no global variable?

```js
(() => {
  const ref = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeoutReference = ', ref);
  }, 1000);
})();

console.log('Is there a global variable ?', ref);
```

With an outside function

```js
function func(ref) {
  console.log('reference : ', ref);
}

(() => {
  const ref = setTimeout(() => func(ref), 1000);
})();

console.log('Is there a global variable ?', ref);
```

Comment: Good point about not having a use for the ID once you're in the function; doing something like this would really only be useful if you were using `setInterval`.

Comment: This is good if your function has the same lexical scope as your timeout. The OP gave an example to @VelimirTchaatchevsky in which that was not the case. I think the OP wants to do this without relying on lexical scope.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myTimeout = setTimeout(test, 1000, "timeout object")

function test(timeout) {
  console.log(myTimeout);
}
```

Now that `myTimeout` is a reference to your timeout you can use it to cancel it with `window.clearTimeout(myTimeout)` or use it for whatever purpose you want.

Comment: `myTImeout` is an integer, not an object. The correct syntax would be `clearTimeout(myTimeout)`

Comment: you made a trick, you just declared "myTimeout" as a global variable which is a bad practice
try this:

function delay(){

  let myTimeout = setTimeout(test, 1000, "timeout object")

}

function test(timeout) {

  console.log(myTimeout);

}

delay()

@VelimirTchatchevsky

Comment: it may be an object or a number, anyway I want a reference to it .. @mhodges

Comment: @xxyy See my answer - there is a way to do this without creating a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the `setTimeout()` function returns an id, store it in a variable and pass it over.

```js
function test(timeout) {
  console.log(timeout2)
}

var timeout2 = setTimeout(test, 1000)
```

**Edit:** *Depending on the environment you are executing it in, sometimes you can't use a variable before declaring it (i.e ES6 Class). You'll have to take care of that.*

Comment: @Herohtar Edited the typo

Comment: it is a bad practise, because you just declared "timeout" as a global variable, not actually passed it as a parameter

Comment: @xxyy There isn't any way to pass it as an actual parameter because you have to assign the returned value to a variable first and that variable can't be passed to `setTimeout` because it hasn't been assigned yet. The only solution is to reference the external variable from the called function as shown here. Global variables are not universally bad, plus the variable used here does not have to be strictly global, it just has to be outside the function that gets called by `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by manipulating the `this` context of your `test()` function being called by the `setTimeout`. You want to use an object property rather than a variable to pass in the timeout reference because the execution will happen asynchronously.

```js
function delay(){ 
  var obj = {};
  obj.timeout = setTimeout(test.bind(obj), 1000) 
} 
function test() { 
  console.log(this.timeout); 
} 
delay();
```

Alternatively, you can just pass the object in as the third parameter to the `setTimeout` function, like so:

```js
function delay(){ 
  var obj = {};
  obj.timeout = setTimeout(test, 1000, obj) 
} 
function test(param) { 
  console.log(param.timeout); 
} 
delay();
```